# Count the matched number of values from whole message in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have below xml as input and from that, I am looping the  segment for-each. From the below data I need the count the number of the same Element-234_8 when Element-235_8= "IK" in the whole message.

So the count would be 5. When I tried count(Loop-HL/Segment-SLN[Element-235_8='IK']/Element-234_8) it's giving 15. So what other functions i need to use it in XSLT 2.0

for example, If I search the value 400200167700010191932355211 from the entire message it's repeated 5 times. So I am trying to get that value count how many times it's reapeataed in whole Loop-HL

```
            <Loop-HL> 
       <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>  25th
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355211</Element-234_8>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355334</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
          <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355440</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
     </Loop-HL>
     <Loop-HL>
         <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355211</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355334</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355440</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
     </Loop-HL>
     <Loop-HL>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355211</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355334</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355440</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
     </Loop-HL>
     <Loop-HL>
         <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355211</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
            <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355334</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355440</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
      </Loop-HL>             
     <Loop-HL>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355211</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355334</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
        <Segment-SLN>
           <Element-234_7>1</Element-234_7>
           <Element-235_8>IK</Element-235_8>
           <Element-234_8>400200167700010191932355440</Element-234_8>
           <Element-235_9>NW</Element-235_9>
           <Element-234_9>1.69</Element-234_9>
        </Segment-SLN>
     </Loop-HL>
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of the logic by which the count is 5.

Comment: Still not clear. Where is the value of 400200167700010191932355211 supposed to come from?

Comment: The value need  from the Element-234_8 attribute

Comment: OK, but why would you choose to count how many times does 400200167700010191932355211 appear and not 400200167700010191932355334 or any other value? Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get. And also add the missing root element to your XML.

Comment: I just mentioned that as an example that number. But I need to search and count the number of reapeats each Element-234_8 element value from the Segment-SLN set

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
count(distinct-values(Loop-HL/Segment-SLN[Element-235_8='IK']/Element-234_8))
```

But it's hard to tell from your description.

You're more likely to get an answer to this kind of question if you simplify it by cutting out extraneous detail: simplify the element names and values, omit those that play no part, get the XML to fit on one page without scrolling.

In some cases, simplifying the problem to explain it to others also means that the answer leaps out at you...

Comment: for example, If I search the value 400200167700010191932355211 from the entire message it's repeated 5 times.  So I am trying to get that value count how many times it's reapeataed in whole Loop-HL

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of occurrences of each distinct value of `Element-234_8` you can do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Loop-HL/Segment-SLN[Element-235_8='IK']" group-by="Element-234_8">
            <grp key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
            </grp>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your example input (after adding the missing root element!) this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <grp key="400200167700010191932355211">5</grp>
   <grp key="400200167700010191932355334">5</grp>
   <grp key="400200167700010191932355440">5</grp>
</output>
```

Comment: I am trying out to apply my XSLT but it seems not to adjust properly. I need to try in other way apply above template

Comment: *"it seems not to adjust properly"* I am afraid I cannot help you with such a vague description. You can see my code working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbBfrFx